# Проблемы с @ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

Пытаюсь сделать связь @ManyToMany. Данные во всех таблицах есть.

1. При попытке получить группы пользователя (`VedUser.getUserGroups()`) всегда возвращается `null` (хотя данные есть)
2. При попытке получить пользователей группы (`VedUserGroup. getUsers()`) вылетает вот такое исключение:

```
SystemErr     R Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: 
Неправильное использование столбца строчного типа, переменной хоста,
константы или функции "DESCRIPTION".. SQLCODE=-134, SQLSTATE=42907,
DRIVER=3.64.82 {prepstmnt 1022573811 
SELECT DISTINCT t2.ID_USER, t4.ID_GROUP, t4.description, t4.name, t4.status 
FROM VED.GROUPS t0 INNER JOIN VED.GROUPS_USERS t1 ON t0.ID_GROUP=t1.ID_GROUP 
INNER JOIN VED.USERS t2 ON t1.ID_USER = t2.ID_USER 
INNER JOIN VED.GROUPS_USERS t3 ON t2.ID_USER = t3.ID_USER 
INNER JOIN VED.GROUPS t4 ON t3.ID_GROUP = t4.ID_GROUP 
ORDER BY t2.ID_USER ASC } [code=-134, state=42907]
```

Я понимаю, что ему не нравится `distinct` со строкой длиной 32074, но я думаю, что дело в том, что запрос как-то странно сгенерировался.

Что нужно исправить, чтобы можно было использовать `VedUser.getUserGroups()` и `VedUserGroup. getUsers()` без ошибок?

База данных:

```
CREATE TABLE "VED     "."GROUPS"  (
          "ID_GROUP" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (  
            START WITH +1  
            INCREMENT BY +1  
            MINVALUE +1  
            MAXVALUE +9223372036854775807  
            NO CYCLE  
            CACHE 20  
            NO ORDER ) , 
          "NAME" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
          "DESCRIPTION" LONG VARCHAR , 
          "STATUS" SMALLINT NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 1 )   
         IN "USERSPACE1" ; 

ALTER TABLE "VED     "."GROUPS" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "GROUPS_PK" PRIMARY KEY
        ("ID_GROUP");

CREATE TABLE "VED     "."USERS"  (
          "ID_USER" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (  
            START WITH +1  
            INCREMENT BY +1  
            MINVALUE +1  
            MAXVALUE +9223372036854775807  
            NO CYCLE  
            CACHE 20  
            NO ORDER ) , 
          "LOGIN" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
          "STATUS" SMALLINT NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 1 )   
         IN "USERSPACE1" ; 

ALTER TABLE "VED     "."USERS" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "USERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY
        ("ID_USER");

CREATE TABLE "VED     "."GROUPS_USERS"  (
          "ID_GROUP" BIGINT NOT NULL , 
          "ID_USER" BIGINT NOT NULL )   
         IN "USERSPACE1" ; 

ALTER TABLE "VED     "."GROUPS_USERS" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "GROUPS_USERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY
        ("ID_GROUP",
         "ID_USER");

ALTER TABLE "VED     "."GROUPS_USERS" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "GROUPS_USERS_GROUPS_FK" FOREIGN KEY
        ("ID_GROUP")
    REFERENCES "VED     "."GROUPS"
        ("ID_GROUP")
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ENFORCED
    ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;

ALTER TABLE "VED     "."GROUPS_USERS" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "GROUPS_USERS_USERS_FK" FOREIGN KEY
        ("ID_USER")
    REFERENCES "VED     "."USERS"
        ("ID_USER")
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ENFORCED
    ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;
```

Класс `VedUserGroup`

```
package org.uit.ved.entities;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * VedEntity Группа пользователей
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUPS", schema="VED")
public class VedUserGroup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Идентификатор
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_GROUP")
    private long id;

    /**
     * Наименование
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * Описание
     */
    @Column(length=32700)
    private String description;

    /**
     * Статус
     */
    private int status;

    /**
     * Пользователи
     */ 
      @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinTable(name="GROUPS_USERS",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID_GROUP", referencedColumnName="ID_GROUP"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID_USER", referencedColumnName="ID_USER")
        )
    private Collection<VedUser> users;

    /**
     * Получить информацию в виде строки
     */
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuffer()
            .append("id=").append(getId()).append("; ")         
            .append("name=").append(getName()).append("; ")
            .append("description=").append(getDescription()).append("; ")
            .append("status=").append(getStatus())
            .toString();
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setUsers(Collection<VedUser> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Collection<VedUser> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }   
}
```

Класс `VedUser`

```
package org.uit.ved.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * VedEntity Пользователь
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS", schema="VED")
public class VedUser implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Идентификатор
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_USER")
    private long id;

    /**
     * Логин
     */
    private String login;

    /**
     * Статус
     */
    private int status;

    /**
     * Группы пользователей
     */ 
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "users")
    private List<VedUserGroup> userGroups;

    /**
     * Получить информацию в виде строки
     */
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuffer()
          .append("id=").append(getId()).append("; ")     
          .append("login=").append(getLogin()).append("; ")
          .append("status=").append(getStatus())
          .toString();
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setUserGroups(List<VedUserGroup> userGroups) {
        this.userGroups = userGroups;
    }

    public List<VedUserGroup> getUserGroups() {
        return userGroups;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо указания длины сделать вот так

```
 @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
```

Comment: не помогло к сожалению